# playbackRate doesn't work on mobile, is there any way to work around it?

Tags: javascript, video, mobile, canvas, accelerometer

I'm building an mobile app with phonecap/appGyver, and I would need to speed/slowdown video according to  phone Accelerometer values.

I get Accelerometer values easy enough, put controlling video seems to be quite impossible. I can change initial value of playbackrate with html5 video tag, but I don't find a way to do it "on the fly".

I have searched and searched with no solution.

Could it be possible by using Canvas-element with some genius setTimeout/setInterval Magic?

Any other ideas?

Comment: To achieve a 2x playback rate (for example): use a `setInterval`, set to run every `n` milliseconds, to increase the video's `currentTime` property by `n` milliseconds. This might not be very performant, though, especially if you're using a very small value of `n` (although large values of `n` will result in awkward jumps).

Comment: Also, I just tried my own suggestion, and it works *terribly*, especially because it utterly destroys the sound.